# Tracking and Filtering Autocomplete Keywords For Custom Analytics

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, statistics, analytics

I am creating an internal customized analytics application, and I have an interesting problem which I would like to hear some perspectives on.

One of the events we are tracking is the user's search keyword. However, this function is implemented as an auto-complete which submits a search after 3 characters. So one search (or 7 characters) is actually submitted as 5 queries... This is a typical autocomplete implementation.

What I am curious about is if anyone has an idea on how to filter the 'junk' searches which have no value vs. the final keyword which the user intended. I would prefer not to implement a "GO" button and break the autocomplete instant filter functionality.

What advice, techniques or algorithms are being used to solve this problem, does anyone have some insight?

I don't think it matters, but this is a PHP/MySQL based SAAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been researching this issue in order to clean up our search tracking as well. It's difficult to find good documentation on how to track searches in a custom implementation.

The closest thing I've found to tracking auto searching is Google's Adwords definition for when an ad impression is registered during Google Instant searches (where results are returned as you type):

> ...when someone searches using Google Instant, an impression can be counted when one of these occur:
>
> - Person begins to type and then clicks anywhere on the page like a search result, ad, or related search
> - Person types a search and then clicks the "Search" button, presses Enter, or selects a predicted query from the drop-down menu
> - Person stops typing, and the results are displayed for a minimum of three seconds

[Impressions: Definition - AdWords Help](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6320?hl=en)

I see two sides of auto search tracking that need to be balanced

1. We want to capture user behavior up to and including him/her finding results or abandoning a search attempt
2. We want clean data, without lots of partial strings that are actually part of a longer search attempt as described in your sample

The key seems to be defining when to report search activity.  Adopting the AdWords rules, or something close to it will put us closer to actual user activity - removing some of the 'junk' searches while users are still typing.  It doesn't seem to be a perfect, catch-all solution, but a starting point to fine tune reporting.

As for not implementing a "Go" button, the rules above actually use that as one of the conditions for reporting a search ("Search" button).  You may be able to do without if your other conditions are sufficient for filtering.